# Can't get SessionContext on EJB

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3, cdi

I can't get a SessionContext object on an EJB. I've tried all the options suggested on [4 Ways to Get EJBContext in EJB 3](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/4-ways-to-get-ejbcontext-in-ejb-3.html) and none of them worked. For example, the following code in my project...

```
@Stateful
public class SecurityService {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    }
}
```

... generates the following exception during deploy:

```
[#|2012-02-28T14:35:02.805-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(5);|The log message is null.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.detectResourceInRA(AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.java:266)
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.processDescriptorForRAReferences(AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.java:211)
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.processDescriptorForRAReferences(AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.java:130)
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.detectReferredRARs(AppSpecificConnectorClassLoaderUtil.java:118)
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorClassLoaderServiceImpl.getConnectorClassLoader(ConnectorClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.getConnectorClassLoader(ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.java:117)
```

If I remove the @Resource annotation it deploys, but does not work (i've tried with JNDI and the other methods cited before).

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1, and my project is JSF with CDI and EJB locally to services with JPA. I've tried injecting SessionContext on CDI beans but received the same errors. My EJB are configured with annotations, and my beans.xml have no configurations (but exists).

One strange thing is that with JNDI lookup I've managed to get an object of type SessionContextImpl on path java:/comp/EJBContext on the @PostConstruct init() method. BUT, it goes to null as soon as another EJB method is called (?) and it does not contain user's roles data (a call to isCallerInRole() throws an exception). Also, it is not an EJBContext object.

I'm packaging everything in a WAR using Maven, and the dependency of Java EE is marked as provided, as the following shows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It seems to me that there is no SessionContext (EJBCOntext) been provided by the container at all. I don't know even if that is possible, and I have no idea on how to solve this.

Please, If you have ANY idea about this, I'll be glad to hear it. Thank you.

Comment: That blog refers to Java EE 5. If you use Java EE 6, and looking at your post it seems you do, it's much simpler: start with this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/ and from other using EJB 3.1

Comment: perissf, I need SessionContext to programatically secure parts of my application (it's too complex to use method-based security). The Java EE 6 Tutorial (the link you posted) shows the same way to do it as the blog that refers to Java EE 5 (reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyl.html#gjgcs). Also, I've looked through the O'Reilly Book "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1", and it says just to use @Resource annotation to get the EJBContext or SessionContext object. I think it is a configuration or environment related problem, but I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've upgraded to Glassfish 3.1.2 and the problem was solved. Now I can inject `javax.ejb.SessionContext` as expected.

Special thanks to @perissf for the help.

Comment: Be welcome. If my answer was useful you can upvote it. If the upgrade has solved your issue, there was probably something wrong in your domain's configuration and creating a brand new domain would have hopefully solved your problem

Answer (score 4):

If your Principal has logged in using [j_security_check](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html), you can inject the `SecurityContext` in an `EJB`, or in a `ManagedBean`, and retrieve Principal's and role's information like this:

```
@Context private SecurityContext context;
....
boolean isInRole = context.isUserInRole("A role");
Principal p = context.getUserPrincipal();
```

Comment: perissf, using _@Context_ gives an exception on deploy as well. And I don't understand: the link you passed of j_security_check (which I'm using) has an example that uses @Resource. Anyway, both does not work. :(

Comment: What exception do you get when deploying?

Comment: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001413 The bean Session bean [class SecurityService with qualifiers [_@Any_ _@Default_ _@Named_]; local interfaces are [SecurityServ
ice] declares passivating scope but has non-serializable dependency com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$ParameterBean@4ebf837a
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413 The bean Session bean [class SecurityService with qualifiers [_@Any_ _@Default_ _@Named_]; local interfaces are [SecurityService] declare
s ..............

Comment: Please update your question, or create a new one, with all the relevant code, including imports, and the exception as well.

Comment: I found a solution: upgrading to Glassfish 3.1.2 solved the problem. Thank you @perissf.