# Can't get EJBContext after deploying a bundle into glassfish

Tags: java, ejb, osgi, glassfish-3

My question based on **[Can't get SessionContext on EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487185/cant-get-sessioncontext-on-ejb)**, I want to inject `EJBContext` into my code

My code is:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

public class EjbContextTest {
    @Resource
    private EJBContext ejbContext;
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;
    ......
}
```

I have a simple testing in activator, just want to verify if I can get an EJBContext by using CDI:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

    EjbContextTest test = new EjbContextTest();

    if (test.getEjbContext() == null) {
       System.out.println("ejbContext is: null" );
    } else
       System.out.println("ejbContext rollback only is: " + 
           test.getEjbContext().getRollbackOnly());
    }
```

When deploying the bundle into glassfish 3.1.2 I can't get an instance of EJBContext:

```
2013-03-29 17:11:20,547|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|
_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|-----------> ejbContext is: null*|#]
```

Please, if you have any suggestion, I will be glad to try it.

Comment: So you're unable to use `@Resource` to inject the contexts?

Comment: Hi kolossus, it doesn't work by using **@Resource**, and also will get a exception in on deploy a bundle into Glassfish

Comment: Hi alex, did you get the reason why @Resource doesn't work on EJBContext?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access EJB session beans or CDI beans by calling their constructors.
Either of the following two should work:

1. Inject using CDI (Or CDI-EJB integration)

   ```
   @Inject
   private EjbContextTest test;
   ```
2. Inject using pure EJB annotation

   ```
   @EJB
   private EjbContextTest test;
   ```

then you can call test.getEjbContext().

This way, @Resource annotations are processed.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For those who still need in the future...

The injecton works using:

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ejbContext;
```

or

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:comp/EJBContext") // adding 'mappedName' with JNDI name
private EJBContext ejbContext;
```